# Implementing Multiple Authentication Methods in a Single Web Application with ReactJS and NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I am developing a web application where users can upload their files or firmware to receive a corresponding report. This web application needs to cater to three distinct deployment scenarios:

1. **Enterprise Level:** In this scenario, users must log in and register with an admin role. If they fail to log in successfully, they should not have access to other parts of the page.
2. **Normal Web Application:** Here, users can upload their files either by logging in or signing up. Authentication is optional for this deployment.
3. **Authentication Required:** For this deployment, users are required to log in or sign up. Authentication is mandatory, and after successful authentication, they can upload their files and obtain reports.

I am building the front-end using ReactJS and the back-end using NodeJS and ExpressJS. How should I implement these two perspectives?